Handling Schema Explicitly in Spark 3.4.1 code
I used to apply some patches to spark code to handle more specific data types and structures explicitly. Older spark code with patches:
private def serializerFor(inputObject: Expression, typeToken: TypeToken[_], schema: DataType): Expression = {

def toCatalystArray(input: Expression, elementType: TypeToken[_], elemType: DataType): Expression = {
  val (dataType, nullable) = inferDataType(elementType)
  if (ScalaReflection.isNativeType(dataType)) {
    val cls = input.dataType.asInstanceOf[ObjectType].cls
    if (cls.isArray && cls.getComponentType.isPrimitive) {
      createSerializerForPrimitiveArray(input, dataType)
    } else {
      createSerializerForGenericArray(input, dataType, nullable = nullable)
    }
  } else {
    createSerializerForMapObjects(input, ObjectType(elementType.getRawType),
      serializerFor(_, elementType, elemType))
  }
}

if (!inputObject.dataType.isInstanceOf[ObjectType]) {
  inputObject
} else {
  typeToken.getRawType match {
    case c if c == classOf[String] => createSerializerForString(inputObject)

    case c if c == classOf[java.time.Instant] => createSerializerForJavaInstant(inputObject)

    case c if c == classOf[java.sql.Timestamp] => createSerializerForSqlTimestamp(inputObject)

    case c if c == classOf[java.time.LocalDate] => createSerializerForJavaLocalDate(inputObject)

    case c if c == classOf[java.sql.Date] => createSerializerForSqlDate(inputObject)

    case c if c == classOf[java.math.BigDecimal] =>
      createSerializerForJavaBigDecimal(inputObject, schema.asInstanceOf[DecimalType])

    case c if c == classOf[java.lang.Boolean] => createSerializerForBoolean(inputObject)
    case c if c == classOf[java.lang.Byte] => createSerializerForByte(inputObject)
    case c if c == classOf[java.lang.Short] => createSerializerForShort(inputObject)
    case c if c == classOf[java.lang.Integer] => createSerializerForInteger(inputObject)
    case c if c == classOf[java.lang.Long] => createSerializerForLong(inputObject)
    case c if c == classOf[java.lang.Float] => createSerializerForFloat(inputObject)
    case c if c == classOf[java.lang.Double] => createSerializerForDouble(inputObject)

    case _ if typeToken.isArray =>
      val baseType = schema match {
        case s: BinaryType => ByteType
        case _ => schema.asInstanceOf[ArrayType].elementType
      }
      toCatalystArray(inputObject, typeToken.getComponentType, baseType)

    case _ if ttIsAssignableFrom(listType, typeToken) =>
      toCatalystArray(inputObject, elementType(typeToken), schema.asInstanceOf[ArrayType].elementType)

    case _ if ttIsAssignableFrom(mapType, typeToken) =>
      val (keyType, valueType) = mapKeyValueType(typeToken)

      createSerializerForMap(
        inputObject,
        MapElementInformation(
          inferExternalType(keyType.getRawType),
          nullable = true,
          serializerFor(_, keyType, schema.asInstanceOf[MapType].keyType)),
        MapElementInformation(
          inferExternalType(valueType.getRawType),
          nullable = true,
          serializerFor(_, valueType, schema.asInstanceOf[MapType].valueType))
      )

    case other if other.isEnum =>
      createSerializerForString(
        Invoke(inputObject, "name", ObjectType(classOf[String]), returnNullable = false))

    case other =>
      val properties = getJavaBeanReadableAndWritableProperties(other)
      val propNames = properties.map { f => (f.getName, f) }.toMap
      // reorder the props w.r.t to given struct type.
      val orderedProps = schema.asInstanceOf[StructType].
        fields.map { f => (propNames.get(f.name).get, f) }
      val fields = orderedProps.map { case (p, f) =>
        val fieldName = p.getName
        val fieldType = typeToken.method(p.getReadMethod).getReturnType
        val fieldValue = Invoke(
          inputObject,
          p.getReadMethod.getName,
          inferExternalType(fieldType.getRawType))
        (fieldName, serializerFor(fieldValue, fieldType, f.dataType))
      }
      createSerializerForObject(inputObject, fields)
  }
}}}

here I have added some extra code(which is given below) to deal with data structures that involve schemas, such as StructType or ArrayType.
//in case of Array
val baseType = schema match {
            case s: BinaryType => ByteType
            case _ => schema.asInstanceOf[ArrayType].elementType
          }
//in case other
val propNames = properties.map { f => (f.getName, f) }.toMap
          // reorder the props w.r.t to given struct type.
          val orderedProps = schema.asInstanceOf[StructType].
            fields.map { f => (propNames.get(f.name).get, f) }
          val fields = orderedProps.map { case (p, f) =>

But now, in Spark 3.4.1, the code flow has changed, and it's difficult to apply these patches. Can Anyone help me with this code editing?
Spark 3.4.1:
private def serializerFor(enc: AgnosticEncoder[_], input: Expression): Expression = enc match {
case _ if isNativeEncoder(enc) => input
case BoxedBooleanEncoder => createSerializerForBoolean(input)
case BoxedByteEncoder => createSerializerForByte(input)
case BoxedShortEncoder => createSerializerForShort(input)
case BoxedIntEncoder => createSerializerForInteger(input)
case BoxedLongEncoder => createSerializerForLong(input)
case BoxedFloatEncoder => createSerializerForFloat(input)
case BoxedDoubleEncoder => createSerializerForDouble(input)
case JavaEnumEncoder(_) => createSerializerForJavaEnum(input)
case ScalaEnumEncoder(_, _) => createSerializerForScalaEnum(input)
case StringEncoder => createSerializerForString(input)
case ScalaDecimalEncoder(dt) => createSerializerForBigDecimal(input, dt)
case JavaDecimalEncoder(dt, false) => createSerializerForBigDecimal(input, dt)
case JavaDecimalEncoder(dt, true) => createSerializerForAnyDecimal(input, dt)
case ScalaBigIntEncoder => createSerializerForBigInteger(input)
case JavaBigIntEncoder => createSerializerForBigInteger(input)
case DayTimeIntervalEncoder => createSerializerForJavaDuration(input)
case YearMonthIntervalEncoder => createSerializerForJavaPeriod(input)
case DateEncoder(true) | LocalDateEncoder(true) => createSerializerForAnyDate(input)
case DateEncoder(false) => createSerializerForSqlDate(input)
case LocalDateEncoder(false) => createSerializerForJavaLocalDate(input)
case TimestampEncoder(true) | InstantEncoder(true) => createSerializerForAnyTimestamp(input)
case TimestampEncoder(false) => createSerializerForSqlTimestamp(input)
case InstantEncoder(false) => createSerializerForJavaInstant(input)
case LocalDateTimeEncoder => createSerializerForLocalDateTime(input)
case UDTEncoder(udt, udtClass) => createSerializerForUserDefinedType(input, udt, udtClass)
case OptionEncoder(valueEnc) =>
  serializerFor(valueEnc, UnwrapOption(externalDataTypeFor(valueEnc), input))

case ArrayEncoder(elementEncoder, containsNull) =>
  if (elementEncoder.isPrimitive) {
    createSerializerForPrimitiveArray(input, elementEncoder.dataType)
  } else {
    serializerForArray(elementEncoder, containsNull, input, lenientSerialization = false)
  }

case IterableEncoder(ctag, elementEncoder, containsNull, lenientSerialization) =>
  val getter = if (classOf[scala.collection.Set[_]].isAssignableFrom(ctag.runtimeClass)) {
    // There's no corresponding Catalyst type for `Set`, we serialize a `Set` to Catalyst array.
    // Note that the property of `Set` is only kept when manipulating the data as domain object.
    Invoke(input, "toSeq", ObjectType(classOf[scala.collection.Seq[_]]))
  } else {
    input
  }
  serializerForArray(elementEncoder, containsNull, getter, lenientSerialization)

case MapEncoder(_, keyEncoder, valueEncoder, valueContainsNull) =>
  createSerializerForMap(
    input,
    MapElementInformation(
      ObjectType(classOf[AnyRef]),
      nullable = keyEncoder.nullable,
      validateAndSerializeElement(keyEncoder, keyEncoder.nullable)),
    MapElementInformation(
      ObjectType(classOf[AnyRef]),
      nullable = valueContainsNull,
      validateAndSerializeElement(valueEncoder, valueContainsNull))
  )

case ProductEncoder(_, fields) =>
  val serializedFields = fields.map { field =>
    // SPARK-26730 inputObject won't be null with If's guard below. And KnownNotNul
    // is necessary here. Because for a nullable nested inputObject with struct data
    // type, e.g. StructType(IntegerType, StringType), it will return nullable=true
    // for IntegerType without KnownNotNull. And that's what we do not expect to.
    val getter = Invoke(
      KnownNotNull(input),
      field.name,
      externalDataTypeFor(field.enc),
      returnNullable = field.nullable)
    field.name -> serializerFor(field.enc, getter)
  }
  createSerializerForObject(input, serializedFields)

case RowEncoder(fields) =>
  val serializedFields = fields.zipWithIndex.map { case (field, index) =>
    val fieldValue = serializerFor(
      field.enc,
      ValidateExternalType(
        GetExternalRowField(input, index, field.name),
        field.enc.dataType,
        lenientExternalDataTypeFor(field.enc)))

    val convertedField = if (field.nullable) {
      exprs.If(
        Invoke(input, "isNullAt", BooleanType, exprs.Literal(index) :: Nil),
        // Because we strip UDTs, `field.dataType` can be different from `fieldValue.dataType`.
        // We should use `fieldValue.dataType` here.
        exprs.Literal.create(null, fieldValue.dataType),
        fieldValue
      )
    } else {
      AssertNotNull(fieldValue)
    }
    field.name -> convertedField
  }
  createSerializerForObject(input, serializedFields)

case JavaBeanEncoder(_, fields) =>
  val serializedFields = fields.map { f =>
    val fieldValue = Invoke(
      KnownNotNull(input),
      f.readMethod.get,
      externalDataTypeFor(f.enc),
      propagateNull = f.nullable,
      returnNullable = f.nullable)
    f.name -> serializerFor(f.enc, fieldValue)
  }
  createSerializerForObject(input, serializedFields)
}

As we can see here they have used Encoders. I tried by applying those patch but got some classCastExceptions.
Thanks in Advance.

We need to see the exceptions if you want our help in fixing them.

You may want to look at building / transforming AgnosticEncoders.  Spark 4 preview 2 pretty much enforces this as your primary way to extend encoder logic but you'd gain the use of spark connect for your types as well as classic spark.
If Spark #48477 gets accepted you could also look at extending / customising the sparkutils Frameless fork encoding for a bit more future proofing but using the existing AgnosticEncoders seems to match your use cases (as seen in your code example).
